# PHP SoapFault Exception : Unsupported Media Type

Tags: php, web, soap, service, fault

When I make a request with PHP Soap I get an error like this : "Unsupported Media Type".

My code :

```
<?php

try{
$soapUrl = "https://n11integrationtest.digitalplanet.com.tr/IntegrationService.asmx?WSDL";

$client = new SoapClient($soapUrl);
$client->__setLocation($soapUrl);
$postData = array(
    "CorporateCode"=>"xxxxxx",
    "LoginName"=>"xxxxxx",
    "Password"=>"xxxxxx"
);

$result = $client->GetFormsAuthenticationTicket($postData);
echo $result->GetFormsAuthenticationTicketResult;
}
catch(Exception $a){
  echo $a;
}
?>
```

The solution for this error is in the document it says: "**If the messageEncoding format is not selected correctly, "Unsupported Media Type" error is received.**"

The app config file is written like this in the document :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<startup>
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"
/> </startup>
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
<basicHttpsBinding>
<binding name="IntegrationServiceSoap"
maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" sendTimeout="23:59:59" receiveTimeout="23:59:59"
maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Mtom" />
</basicHttpsBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
<endpoint
address="https://n11integrationtest.digitalplanet.com.tr/IntegrationService.asmx"
binding="basicHttpsBinding" bindingConfiguration="IntegrationServiceSoap"
contract="applicationName.IntegrationServiceSoap" name="IntegrationServiceSoap" />
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

So, how can edit my php code ? Thanks..:)